# error while cloning git repository into zip archive

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, git

I have a code, which launching bash script to upload repo into zip. The problem is it works localy, but in production environment i'm getting error.

```
import { createReadStream, unlinkSync } from 'fs';
import { exec } from 'child_process';
const { promisify } = require('util');
import * as shortUuid from 'short-uuid';

const execute = promisify(exec);
const idCreator = shortUuid();

export const bundle = async (url) => {
    const archive = `${idCreator.uuid()}.zip`;
    const [scheme, rest] = url.split('://');
    const command = `sh src/marketplace/utils/scripts/bundle-app.sh ${scheme}://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@${rest} ${archive}`;
    console.log(command)
    const result = await execute(command);
    return createReadStream(archive).on('close', () => unlinkSync(archive));
};
```

Command looks like:

```
sh src/marketplace/utils/scripts/bundle-app.sh https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@github.com/companyX/app-adweek-360-video c3a65230-7d64-4772-8a03-71d5a8c824dd.zip
```

bundle-app.sh file:

```
set -e

source=$1
archive=$2
target=$(echo $2 | sed "s/.zip//")
git clone $source $target
zip -9 -r --exclude=*.git* $archive $target
rm -rf $target
```

Error:

```
"Command failed: sh src/marketplace/utils/scripts/bundle-app.sh https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@github.com/companyX/app-adweek-360-video c3a65230-7d64-4772-8a03-71d5a8c824dd.zip\nCloning into 'c3a65230-7d64-4772-8a03-71d5a8c824dd'...\nsrc/marketplace/utils/scripts/bundle-app.sh: 9: src/marketplace/utils/scripts/bundle-app.sh: zip: not found\n"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to put the entire commit history into the zip, or just the state of the repository at a specific point?

Comment: entire commit history

Comment: OK. Are you sure the `zip` binary is installed on whatever system runs the script, and that the account that runs the script has `zip` in its PATH?

Comment: It looks like `zip` is not installed, or it is installed but not in a directory which is part of the `PATH` environment variable. You could use `type zip`/`which zip` and `echo "$PATH"` to troubleshoot

Comment: thanks so much. Yes, you was write. I needed to set up zip, using bash script